# Using of "facilitate" with a gerund

Tags: word-usage

Can I say "To facilitate doing something"? Should I use "task, process" or something?

> **To facilitate specifying anchors**, the page elements are highlighted as the user hover the mouse over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a gerund can be used where a noun is expected.

Also, add "*cursor*" or "*pointer*" after "*mouse*", the user isn't really moving *the device* over the page elements.